# Preserving custom made word styles in word html

Tags: html, css, ms-word

I have to make a release notes document in word based on an xml export from Jira.

Some of the fields that we need in the release notes document are rich text enabled. In reality the output is html styled text.

To be able to mix the html text and the plain text from Jira, we opted to use the word html (save a word document as web page) as a template.
Then we use xslt to add the needed values from the xml export into the word html template.

This seems to be working quite ok, but we ran into a problem.

The release notes format in word has a lot of styles (some of them are custom build)

But in the document we get when opening the transformed file (thus technically HTML) we only get 2 styles: Normal and heading1

(I prepared 2 screenshots, but I can't post images yet)

My question now is:

Is there a way to add these styles to the word html part so these can still be used by our users to edit the document after it is generated.

I thought there had to be something I could add here to insert these styles. But I can't seem to figure out what. 
there is a style part in the html, so that is what I primarily have been looking at.

any help would be appreciated. Even if you just point me to some documentation about word html, or to someone who might know this.

Kind regards

Peter

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach, you could consider docx4j.XHTMLImport.

If your incoming XHTML contains @class values with the same names as styles in the target docx, then the converted content will use those styles.